# Angular 5 production build throwing error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular app using version 5.2 which is throwing the following error when building for production (does not throw the error when running the app locally or running a standard build.)

ERROR in Either route or analyzedModules has to be specified!

Upon research the error is thrown by the ahead of time compiler but I'm not sure what could be causing it, if anyone has suggestions of where to look that would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: As requested here is the error stack
ng build --prod

Date: 2018-05-17T10:23:10.379Z
Hash: a96f44ca3fbe47707a02
Time: 10740ms
chunk {0} runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.5283ab92ad436ab9264c.css (styles) 116 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.bb453547f4804812c2d3.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.324541d43b39aaa6d019.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Either route or analyzedModules has to be specified!

Comment: can you post the entire error stack here ?

Comment: @candidJ I've edited it into the post

Comment: my guess is your are missing a Child Route somewhere.  For main app module : `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`
For sub modules use `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`

Comment: could you post what error stack is shown in browser console as well

Comment: There is no error in the browser, this is happening in the command line when building the app for production (ng build --prod). It doesn't happen when I run the app for testing (ng serve) and everything runs as I would expect when running locally. I only encountered this issue when I finished development on a new feature and tried to deploy it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realised I was using version 6.0.1 of the Angular Compiler CLI with an Angular 5.2 app. I reverted the version of the Compiler CLI to 5.2.11 and the issue is resolved.