# ERROR in Either route or analyzedModules has to be specified

Tags: angular, typescript

After updated ANGULAR CLI 6.0.8 I m not about to build my Angular APP, it's giving the error "ERROR in Either route or analyzedModules has to be specified!"

here is my Package.Config file

```
{
  "name": "PM",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "doc:build": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "doc:serve": "compodoc -s",
    "doc:buildandserve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -s"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^1.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^5.2.0",
    "EverCookie": "^1.0.24",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^2.0.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "digi_logger": "^1.0.0",
    "digi_user_rights": "^1.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "install": "^0.12.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^3.0.5",
    "ng2-signalr": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.4",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.4.0",
    "npm": "^6.2.0",
    "primeng": "^5.2.0",
    "push-notification": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "session-timeout": "^1.3.3",
    "signalr": "^2.2.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 production build throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389417/angular-5-production-build-throwing-error)